# Can i open an Lg backup file on my desktop?

Tags: lg

i had an LG G4 phone that i backed up all my photos and contacts to, and I have the file saved on my desktop. I now have a samsung galaxy note 4 and i want to open the files, and have been unable to. How can i extract the files without having an LG phone?

Comment: How did you make a backup of the photos/contacts?  Was it a certain program?

Comment: it was with lg backup. Ive tried downloading the desktop version, but without an lg phone, it wont open for me

Comment: I am no LG user, so excuse my lack of knowledge. Does your backup have a .IMG extension, a .ab extension, or none of the above? IMG is a nandroid backup, and ab can be restored with adb

Comment: .lbf file extension